# Set node to random Y position without overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to creat nodes at different Y possition without overlapping. The world node dosent move, so I cant increment the Y value in the loop, because I want the position to be random

// The func that I use to creat the random number

```
func randRange (lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
   return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
}
```

// Creat node at random Y position

```
for var i = 0; i < 4; i++
{

    var minY:Int = -Int(self.frame.size.height / 2 );
    var maxY:Int = Int(self.frame.size.height / 2);
    var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(randRange(minY, upper:maxY));

    var node: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 5));
    node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2 + node.frame.size.width/2, y);
    world.addChild(node);

}
```

1. Solution one

Creat an array and put there the every Y position and to check if there is already set. And then the node leave the screen to remove it from the array

But I dont how to search in the array and remove from it

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but I would like to clear some things up with this question.  You would create an array and store only the nodes that have already been created and still exist (Not an array of every Y position).  When you attempt to create a new node and generate a random Y value, traverse through the array and check if any of the nodes have this Y value already.  If its a repeat, call the randRange to generate  a new random number and see if that new value is already taken.  Repeat until you find a value you can use or have the maximum number of nodes already visible.

Comment: The array will store only the Y positions that exist already.

Comment: Store the entire node, this way you can easily have access to remove it if it is (popped, destroyed, etc).   You wouldn't search the array, you would have to use a for loop or something similar to run through each node and check if the Y position is the same as your random number.

Comment: I add the node with arrayNode.addObject(node); but how to search in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for how to search an array:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayNode.count;i++)
{
    if(arrayNode[0].yPosition == randomNumber) //Random number
          //Pick another number
}
```

Deleting from an array can be a bit more tricky.  However, if you make the array an NSMutableArray, you get access to the removeObject: method.  When you need to remove the node, you should have access to it, probably through some contact event.  You can pass this node into:

```
[arrayNode removeObject: yourNode];
```